# Animation origin of Highcharts library

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to build up a Highchart step-by-step. I got it working, but I'm not happy with the way it gets animated. The animation origin is the y-axis in this case, but I want the bars to rise up from the x-axis.
They do rise up from the x-axis when I have data visible on load. However, I want to start with an empty chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/ueC9g/1/

This is how I initialize highcharts:

```
new Highcharts.Chart ({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'columnChart'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Great chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['<5', '5-9', '10-14','15-19','20-24','25-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60-69','>69'],
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        title: {
            text: 'Age'
        },
        showEmpty: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Some numbers'
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        showEmpty: true,
        alternateGridColor: '#eee'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'male',
        data: [1, 1, 5, 8, 10, 15, 19, 14, 10, 8, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'female',
        data: [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 4, 4, 3, 2]
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            events: {

            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When showing/hiding series, highcharts animates the change to the axis instead of the series itself.  I can't find anyway to change this behavior.  As a workaround, instead of showing/hiding the series why not add it as new on the click:

```
var i = 0;

$('#addBar').click(function(){
    try {
        if (i == 0) {
            columnChart.addSeries({name:'male',data:[1, 1, 5, 8, 10, 15, 19, 14, 10, 8, 4]});
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            columnChart.addSeries({name:'female',data:[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 4, 4, 3, 2]});
        }
        i++;                
    } catch(e){
        console.dir(e);
    }
});
```

I'd set up an initial empty series in my config too, so that the axes draw on start:

```
series: [{visible: false, showInLegend: false}],
```

See updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ueC9g/2/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm doing it like that.

Comment: One more question: Is there a way to display the legend even though no data is displayed in the graph?

Comment: What would you display an empty box?  Or  the two series there just disabled?

Comment: The two disabled series.

Answer (score 0):

Please familair with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/VcJ4K/5/

```
 $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i, point) {

        window.setInterval(function() {
            point.update(point.y2); 
        }, 500);

    });
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I get the same problem when I start off with all bars hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/VcJ4K/6/

Comment: Sebastian rather suggest to not use show(), but add()/udpate() points.

Comment: I see. I did it like Mark suggested in the other answer, but thanks for the explanation.